# How do you write into a .csv file in a python program?

Tags: python-3.x

I did this but i got an error - 'writer is not defined'.

```
import csv

x = {1,2,3}
file = open('xyz.csv', 'w')
write = csv.writer(file)
for i in x:
    writer.writerow((i,3))
file.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never defined `writer`. You said `write = csv.writer(file)`, consider changing it to `writer = csv.writer(file)`.

Your code will be:

```
import csv

x = {1,2,3}
file = open('xyz.csv', 'w')
writer = csv.writer(file)
for i in x:
    writer.writerow((i,3))
file.close()
```